# Webpack --watch doesn't trigger for CSS files in specific directory

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, postcss, webpack-3

Using `webpack --watch`, changes to .pcss (PostCSS) files are not picked up when within [src/components/Main/]. Changes to .js files are picked up fine as well as .pcss files in other directories. Because my web app is isomorphic, `ExtractTextPlugin` is used to squish all the CSS together and push it into a single file.

[Full code on GitHub.](https://github.com/RightThisMinute/owl-front-end)

This is on macOS 10.12.X.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

const babelPresetEnvExclude = require('./config/babel-preset-env.exclude')


const babelPluginRelay = ['relay', { schema: 'data/schema.graphqls', }]

const styleRules = {
    test: /\.p?css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: { importLoaders: 1 },
            },
            'postcss-loader',
        ],
    }),
}

const fileRules = {
    test: /\.((pn|sv|jpe?)g|gif)$/,
    use: ['file-loader'],
}

const server = {

    target: 'node',
    entry: './build/unbundled/server.js',

    output: {
        filename: 'server.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: [babelPluginRelay],
                    },
                }],
            },
            styleRules,
            fileRules,
        ]
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        }),
        // Overwrites the same file created by the browser webpack config. A loader
        // needs to be specified to take care of the import statements and it wont
        // work without also outputting a file. There has to be a better way to
        // handle this, but I want to focus on other parts for now.
        // @todo: make this less bad.
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/main.css'),
    ]
}


const browser = {

    target: 'web',
    entry: './build/unbundled/browser.js',

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/public')
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ['env', {
                                debug: true,
                                useBuiltIns: true,
                                targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions'] },
                                exclude: babelPresetEnvExclude
                            }]
                        ],
                        plugins: [babelPluginRelay],
                    },
                }],
            },
            styleRules,
            fileRules,
        ]
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css'),
    ]

}

console.log('NODE_ENV', JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'))

module.exports = [browser, server]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rtm-owl",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "boring@example.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "relay": "relay-compiler --src ./build/unbundled --schema data/schema.graphqls",
    "build": "tsc --pretty && npm run relay && webpack --progress",
    "debug": "npm run build && node --inspect build/server.js",
    "debug-brk": "npm run build && node --inspect-brk build/server.js",
    "start": "node build/server.js",
    "watch": "concurrently --kill-others 'tsc --pretty --watch' 'relay-compiler --src ./build/unbundled --schema data/schema.graphqls --watch' 'webpack --watch' 'nodemon build/server.js'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.6.1",
    "@types/debug": "^0.0.30",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.36",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/isomorphic-fetch": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.71",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.32",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/react-chartjs-2": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.47",
    "@types/serialize-javascript": "^1.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "^4.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "postcss-css-variables": "^0.7.0",
    "postcss-import": "^10.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "postcss-nested": "^2.1.0",
    "relay-compiler": "^1.1.0",
    "relay-runtime": "^1.1.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "^1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "debug": "^2.6.8",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "farce": "^0.2.1",
    "found": "^0.3.1",
    "found-relay": "^0.3.0-alpha.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.5.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-relay": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the code up on github?

Comment: @MukeshSoni Just pushed it: [owl-front-end](https://github.com/RightThisMinute/owl-front-end).

Comment: I tried it. changed stuff in variables.pcss and `webpack --watch` rebuilt the whole thing.

Comment: @MukeshSoni Thanks for taking a look. You're right, that does work. It seems that the problem is localized to the .pcss files in [src/components/Main]. `webpack --watch` sees changes in other places, just not in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar behaviour, `webpack --watch` does not react to changes in css files on macOS 10.14. I used the basic `style-loader` and `css-loader` and require my css files like `require('./style.css')`.

**Solved** by switching to [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon). In my `package.json` the following setup runs webpack whenever js or css files become modified.

```
...
scripts: {
  "build": "webpack",
  "watchbuild": "nodemon --watch ./ --ext js,css --ignore dist --exec \"npm run build\"",
  ...
},
devDependencies: {
  "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
  "webpack": "^4.39.3",
  ...
}
...
```

The setup can be easily customized to watch more file types and to execute a series of commands. For example `nodemon --watch ./ --ext js,ejs,css,pcss --ignore dist --exec 'npm run lint && npm run build'` will also watch ejs templates and pcss styles and run linter before build.

**Note** that I had to ignore my build directory `dist` to prevent infinite build loop. Note also `\"` instead of `'` to provide compatibility between macOS and Windows.